# Replace TabItem with RadioButton

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm using Prism for UI composition and would need a way to switch the active view by a RadioButton. I want a group of RadioButtons that would change the desired view when checked. I thought the TabControl would be perfect for this. I thought I could just use a style to change the template of the TabItem to a RadioButton, but it is not switching tabs with the RadioButton is selected. Here's the template I have for the TabItem

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"
                 Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

I thought that should make the tab selected when the RadioButton is checked, but that doesn't appear to happen. What am I doing wrong or is there another way to achieve the same result?

Also is there a way to make the first view of the TabControl active? I tried SelectedIndex="0" on the tab control, but that doesn't seem to set the IActiveAware.IsActive on the view.

Here is the exact code that I'm using for styling the TabControl and TabItem

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource mainRegionControlForegroundBrush}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content.DataContext.Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Content="{TemplateBinding TabControl.SelectedContent}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TabControl.SelectedContentTemplate}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. TemplateBinding wasn't updating the parent property, so IsSelected was never set on the TabItem. I changed the binding to

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `RadioButton` that uses a `Border` element:

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TabTemplate}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Content="Tab 1" />
    <RadioButton Content="Tab 2" />
    <RadioButton Content="Tab 3" />
</StackPanel>
```

I also added a basic `Trigger` so that you can see how to `Style` the selected item differently from the other tabs.

---

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, I clearly didn't read your question properly. To do it the other way around, it's a lot more work and unfortunately, *you* are going to have to do your bit because there is just too much code. So to start with, your example code didn't work because you were trying to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `TabControl`, whereas you *actually* just need to define one for the `TabItem`.

The first step to do this is to actually define a new `ControlTemplate` for the whole `TabControl` which *includes* the `ControlTemplate` for the `TabItem`. Your example didn't work because you failed to replicate a lot of parts of the default `ControlTemplate`, so we need to do that. How? Well we can find the default `ControlTemplate` in the [TabControl Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

So after looking at that, you'll understand why I can't put all that code here. At first, you basically need to use that exact XAML to reproduce the default `ControlTemplate`... when it is all working as normal, *then* you can start to tweak it to your requirements. If you look down the linked page, you'll see this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            ...
```

This is where the default `ControlTemplate` for the `TabItem` starts. Looking further down, underneath the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`, you should see this:

```
      <Border x:Name="Border"
              Margin="0,0,-4,0"
              BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
              CornerRadius="2,12,0,0">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Border.Background>

          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                               EndPoint="0,1">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                              Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                              Offset="1.0" />
              </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          </LinearGradientBrush>

        </Border.Background>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          Margin="12,2,12,2"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
      </Border>
```

*This* is what defines what a `TabItem` should look like and is where you need to add your `RadioButton` (instead of this `Border` and it's contents). You'll probably also need to remove or adjust anything that references the old controls, eg. in the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` section.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do the opposite, style a TabItem as a RadioButton.

Comment: Thanks. So do I need to copy what the radio button looks like and not use an actual radio button for the control template of the tabitem? I posted my styles for the tab control in my question.

Comment: No, you can use an actual `RadioButton`.

Comment: So if you look at the updated code I posted in my question, what am I doing wrong? I can get the RadioButton to show up correctly, but when it's clicked, nothing happens. It does not change the content of the TabControl. If I remove the Template from the TabItem Style, the TabItem functions correctly.

Comment: I don't know... what errors do you have in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't receive any errors in the output window. It's like the binding between IsChecked and IsSelected is not working. Or maybe a click event isn't being bubbled up, but I thought the TemplateBinding to IsSelected would achieve the same affect.

Comment: One thing you didn't do was to set the `GroupName` property on the `RadioButton`. This isn't causing this problem, but it was causing a problem. Did you start like I suggested, by implementing the default `ControlTemplate` locally? You should get it working first and then tweak bit by bit... maybe something else that is required in the default `ControlTemplate` is missing from yours? Either way, I have to go now, so I trust you can complete this on your own... just keep experimenting, you're on the right track.

Comment: So I narrowed it down to something with the radio button. I added a stackpanel and put the radio button in it. I removed the content presenter from the radio button and added it to the stackpanel. I can click the content presenter and the tab is selected. If I click on the radio button, nothing happens. I'm thinking it has something to do with an event not being bubbled up to the parent.

Comment: I found what was causing my problem. TemplateBinding didn't update the parent property so IsSelected was never set on the tab item. I used IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" instead of the TemplateBinding and it worked like a charm. Thanks for all the help Sheridan. I spent 2 days trying to figure this out.